# What is our stance on questions about the rationale behind a drug's price?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions about the rationale behind a drug's price? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

[Example](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/8755/43)

> Question: Why is apokyn so expensive?
>
> I understand that [Apomorphine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apomorphine) has been around for a very long
>   time, at least 60 years, and it is very easy to make being a
>   derivative of morphine.
>
> Why then does it cost $5000 for a 5-dose injector?

Answer (score 3):

These types of questions should be off-topic, as they have more to do with economics than health. Generally, when drugs that are very cheap to make, but have very high prices it is because of monetary reasons. That is not what this site's scope should cover.